# Google maps directions with more detailed points

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently if I search for a route using the `DirectionsService` it will return me a route with 1 or more legs, and each leg contains multiple steps. Each step seems to correspond to turns in a road. For example, if I drive 2km along street 1 and street1 is entirely a straight road, it will only contain two points (steps) that I can traverse over on that street. The first step will be where the journey along street 1 begins and the next step will be where the journey ends. This makes sense, but unfortunately I'm animating a journey along a map with a marker. This results in huge jumps on the map when there are long straight steps in the journey.

Is there any way to get more detailed steps so that the distance (by road) between each step will be more or less linear?

Comment: can you please post your code so we can see what you have so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move along the straight line between vertices on the polyline.

See [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html) for one way to do that.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
  var markerArray = [];
  var position;
  var marker = null;
  var polyline = null;
  var poly2 = null;
  var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  
    var myPano;   
    var panoClient;
    var nextPanoId;
  var timerHandle = null;

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        marker.myname = label;
        // gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    return marker;
}


function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    
    // Create a map and center it on Manhattan.
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    address = 'new york'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    });
    
    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    
    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
  }

  
  
    var steps = []

    function calcRoute(){

if (timerHandle) { clearTimeout(timerHandle); }
if (marker) { marker.setMap(null);}
polyline.setMap(null);
poly2.setMap(null);
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map
    }
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: travelMode
        };

        // Route the directions and pass the response to a
        // function to create markers for each step.
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var route = response.routes[0];
        startLocation = new Object();
        endLocation = new Object();

        // For each route, display summary information.
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
          if (i == 0) { 
            startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
            startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
            // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
            marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
          }
          endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
          endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);



            }
          }
        }

        polyline.setMap(map);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
//        createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
    map.setZoom(18);
    startAnimation();
    }                                                    
 });
}
  

  
      var step = 50; // 5; // metres
      var tick = 100; // milliseconds
      var eol;
      var k=0;
      var stepnum=0;
      var speed = "";
      var lastVertex = 1;


//=============== animation functions ======================
      function updatePoly(d) {
        // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

        if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
           if (poly2.getPath().getLength()>1) {
             poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength()-1)
           }
           poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
        } else {
          poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),endLocation.latlng);
        }
      }


      function animate(d) {
// alert("animate("+d+")");
        if (d>eol) {
          map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
          marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
          return;
        }
        var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
        map.panTo(p);
        marker.setPosition(p);
        updatePoly(d);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
      }


function startAnimation() {
        eol=polyline.Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
        // map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(polyline.getAt(0),G_START_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(polyline.getVertex(polyline.getVertexCount()-1),G_END_ICON));
        // marker = new google.maps.Marker({location:polyline.getPath().getAt(0)} /* ,{icon:car} */);
        // map.addOverlay(marker);
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:10});
        // map.addOverlay(poly2);
        setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}


//=============== ~animation funcitons =====================
// from epolys_v3.js
// http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js
/*********************************************************************\
* .Distance()       returns the length of the poly path               *
* .GetPointAtDistance() returns a GLatLng at the specified distance   *
*                   along the path.                                   *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Reurns null if the path is shorter than that      *
* .GetIndexAtDistance() returns the vertex number at the specified    *
*                   distance along the path.                          *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Returns null if the path is shorter than that      *
***********************************************************************/
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(newLatLng) {
  var EarthRadiusMeters = 6378137.0; // meters
  var lat1 = this.lat();
  var lon1 = this.lng();
  var lat2 = newLatLng.lat();
  var lon2 = newLatLng.lng();
  var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = EarthRadiusMeters * c;
  return d;
}
// === A method which returns the length of a path in metres ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Distance = function() {
  var dist = 0;
  for (var i=1; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  }
  return dist;
}
// === A method which returns a GLatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
  var dist=0;
  var olddist=0;
  for (var i=1; (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  var p1= this.getPath().getAt(i-2);
  var p2= this.getPath().getAt(i-1);
  var m = (metres-olddist)/(dist-olddist);
  return new google.maps.LatLng( p1.lat() + (p2.lat()-p1.lat())*m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng()-p1.lng())*m);
}
// === A method which returns the Vertex number at a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  var dist=0;
  var olddist=0;
  for (var i=1; (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {return null;}
  return i;
}
```

```css
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;margin:0px;font-family: Helvetica,Arial;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Complex</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="scripts/v3_epoly.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="tools">
    start:
    <input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="union square, NY"/>
    end:
    <input type="text" name="end" id="end" value="times square, NY"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();"/>
</div>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Accepted this answer as I can probably adapt the code for my purposes. A couple of questions. Why do you create a new polyline in this example? From debugging this code it seems that by creating a polyline from the steps of the route, you get more latlng points?

Comment: `by creating a polyline from the steps of the route, you get more latlng points` More latlng points than what? Are you trying to use the "overview_path", which the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults) describes `contains an array of LatLngs that represent an approximate (smoothed) path of the resulting directions.`, that doesn't have all the points.

Comment: That should work (at least to get all the points of the first leg).  It sounds like the problem was interpolating points along a line between 2 points.